# why collide_mask is significantly slower than collide_rect in pygame?

Tags: python, performance, pygame

i have this piece of code here to add collision to my pygame game:

```py
        collidable_sprites = self.tiles["ground"].sprites. Sprites() + self.tiles["fg_machines"].sprites.sprites()
        for sprite in collidable_sprites:
            if sprite.rect.colliderect(player.rect):
```

and this is working smooth at 60 fps (my fps for clock.tick)
but, of course, that collision detection is very rough unless your game is just rectangles - which is not true in my case.
so, i switched to mask collision:

```py
        collidable_sprites = self.tiles["ground"].sprites.sprites() + self.tiles["fg_machines"].sprites.sprites()
        for sprite in collidable_sprites:
            if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(player, sprite):
```

which works better, but drops my fps to 20.
i understanding that this far harder to calculate,
but is this a good alternative to do it with 3x frame drop?

Answer (score 3):

[`pygame.Rect.colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) performs a bounding box test and [`pygame.sprite.collide_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) performs a collision test based on the `.rect` attributes of the [`pygame.sprite.Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite).

[`pygame.sprite.collide_mask`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_mask) performs a collision test based on the `.rect` and `.mask` attributes of the `pygame.sprite.Sprite`. If the sprites does not have a `.mask` attribute, the masks must even be created on the fly.

`collide_mask` is slower than `collide_rect` because it performs a collision test based on overlapping pixels, while `collide_rect` only performs an axis-aligned bounding box test. A bounding box test can be performed with a single condition. The mask test, on the other hand, must first find the overlapping area of the rectangles and then the overlapping pixels, and therefore depends on the size of the overlapping area of the two areas respectively masks.
Basically `collide_mask` does what `collide_rect` does to find the intersection of the rectangles, but after that it has to iterate through the mask bits to detect if overlapping bits are set.

The first thing you should try to do to improve the performance of your code is to create the masks in advance with [`pygame.mask.from_surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface). e.g.:

```py
class SpriteObject(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, image):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (x, y))
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```